# highcharts waterfall stack only internediate series

Tags: highcharts

New to Highcharts, trying to generate waterfall chart with stacking only on intermediate stack. (image below)

Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQI4I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve something like this by adding these stacking columns as an additional series to the waterfall chart. I think that everything is clearly showed in the demo.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tmyrk21f/

```
{
    type: 'column',
    pointPadding: 0,
    stacking: 'normal',
    data: [
      // First stack
      {
        y: 50000,
        x: 0,
        color: 'red'
      }, {
        y: 50000,
        x: 0,
        color: 'orange'
      }, {
        y: 20000,
        x: 0,
      },
            // Second stack
            {
        y: 500000,
        x: 3,
        color: 'red'
      }, {
        y: 400000,
        x: 3,
        color: 'orange'
      }, {
        y: 20000,
        x: 3,
      },
            // Third stack
            {
        y: 145000,
        x: 6,
        color: 'red'
      }, {
        y: 100000,
        x: 6,
        color: 'orange'
      }, {
        y: 100000,
        x: 6,
      }
    ]
  }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.groupPadding

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.stacking